# Cannot enable on major publishing trigger while adding a workflow to list

Tags: approval

My Doc library is major and minor versioning enabled.

I've created SharePoint 2010 workflow for all content types, put there a one single  Action "Start Approval(n) process on Current Item with MyUser", changed the  Sample5.xoml.wfconfig.xml file with adding:

and in MetaData section:

Manual;#OnNewItem;#OnItemUpdate;#OnMajorCheckIn

But I still cannot check "Start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item"

I'm doing all this to create a custom approval workflow but even in simplest form like this main start option is not available for me.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with PowerShell.
I need to **add the workflow first** than with PS get it'assosiation ID from WorkflowAssociations lib property than assign this id to DefaultContentApprovalWorkflowId lib property and update the lib.
Works.

```
$web = get-spweb -identity "*Site URL*"
$mylib = $web.Lists["*Library Name*"]
$wa_guid = ($mylib.WorkflowAssociations | where {$_.Name -like *Workflow unique name*}).Id
$mylib.DefaultContentApprovalWorkflowId = $wa_guid
$mylib.Update()
```

Comment: I would be a pleasure to see this PowerShell code :-)